# Java: API for Screen Capturing

Tags: java, api, screen-capture

Is there any API in java that takes to inputs as 2 coordinates and takes a snap shot of screen marked by that co-ordinates?
I want to API to return IMAGE format.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is [`java.awt.Robot`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html).

Comment: Thanks .It would be greate if you show some pseudocode

Comment: i want the entire part of scrren that is marked by the 2 points to be  retunred in form of image.I cant find it in given class

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any API in java that takes to inputs as 2 coordinates and takes a snap shot of screen marked by that co-ordinates? ..

Use [Robot.createScreenCapture(Rectangle)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture%28java.awt.Rectangle%29).

> ..I want to API to return IMAGE format.

What is IMAGE format?  [ImageIO.write(RenderedImage, String, File)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write%28java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29) will write in GIF, JPEG & PNG formats.  Further formats are offered by JAI.